# Real alternatives to Clojure's concurrency primitives in Scala

Tags: scala, concurrency, clojure

In Clojure I have four primitives to manage concurrency scenarios

1. Refs - manage *coordinated, synchronous* changes to shared state
2. Atoms - manage *uncoordinated, synchronous* changes to shared state
3. Agents - manage *asynchronous* changes to shared state
4. Vars - manage *thread-local* state

**My questions is - is there a mature equivalent to each of these in Scala?**

**Assumptions** - I'm going to assume that:

- Actors are a different way to solve the problems that agents do - but they are no means a drop-in replacement
- I'm aware there are agent libraries in Scala - I'm curious to know if they're considered mature

Comment: Scala vars do nothing to provide thread-safety.  But then most good, functional Scala coders would tend to only use vars within contexts that safely encapsulated the mutable state, where they used them at all.

Comment: @flavian Aren't those actor libraries? If so, see OP's first assumption.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of the concurrency constructs you listed for Clojure [are based in software transactional memory.](http://clojure.org/concurrent_programming) Because of that, I think you're basically just asking about STM support in Scala. According to the [Akka documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/scala/stm.html), the best choice for STM in Scala is [ScalaSTM](http://nbronson.github.io/scala-stm/), and they say it's actually going to be included in the Scala Standard Library sometime in the future.

ScalaSTM supports Agents and Refs (which I believe were actually based on the Clojure versions). I think the corollary of an Atom would be the *Ref.single* type, which is just a ref that you can use outside of an `atomic` block.

Depending on your use case, a good substitute for `var` would be Java's [`ThreadLocal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) or Scala's [`DynamicVariable`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.DynamicVariable). Use `ThreadLocal` if all you want is thread-local data, but if you actually need dynamic binding, then I think you need `DynamicVariable`.

Comment: Actually, only Clojure Refs use STM.  Atoms are not transactional in the sense that you can not atomically update multiple atoms.  They do not participate in STM transactions.  Agents participate slightly, but only in the sense that any agent dispatches are delayed until the transaction finishes successfully.  However, if an agent action fails, it does not cause the transaction to fail.  Vars provide thread-local values (with dynamic vars being a special case of this).  So each type provides a different way of managing (potentially concurrent) state, with different use cases for each.

Comment: @NathanDavis - You're right that atoms don't really need STM. However, you can think of operations on atoms as a degenerate case of STM, and all you need to implement it is CAS. That's why ScalaSTM provides the Ref.single implementation that lets you do things like swap and CAS on a Ref without explicitly wrapping it in an atomic block. I think I see your point though, and I'll edit my answer so the wording is more clear.